# typescript: type of derived class in superclass

Tags: typescript, inheritance

I have an abstract typescript class:

```
abstract class Abstract {

  constructor (public parent?: Abstract) {
  }

}
```

Now I define 2 subclasses:

```
class Sub1 extends Abstract {

}

class Sub2 extends Abstract {

}
```

parent is of type Abstract, so this is possible:

```
let sub1 = new Sub1 ();

let sub2 = new Sub2 (sub1);
```

But I want that `Sub1.parent` must have type `Sub1` and `Sub2.parent` must have type `Sub2`. How do I specify this in the definition of Abstract?

Answer (score 1):

Your both classes are identically as of now - so it is correct to be able to use any instance of `Abstract`. If you add member fields to the class, then the tscompiler will complain e.g..

```
class Sub2 extends Abstract {
    public test: number;
    constructor (parent?: Sub2) {
        super(parent);
    }
}

let sub2 = new Sub2 (sub1); // will not work
```